Сборка проекта стопорится на парсинге
Установлен jdk-23. Проект maven, редактор Intellij Idea 2021.2.3.
При запуске main метода основного класса, сборка проекта стопорится на том, что в нижней части Idea зависает незавершенный процесс "Parsing java...". Это стало появляться при смене версии Java. Решение пока - только перезапуск Idea.
Увеличил размер кучи при сборке: File\Settings\Build, Execution, Deployment\Compiler|Shared build process heap size до 4096 - результат не изменился.
В логах Help\Show Log in Explorer появлется четыре записи:
INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (...) RunManager took 40 ms.
через 2 минуты:
INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
WARN - ConfigurableExtentionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: language for id: preferences.language.Kotlin.scripting
INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1

Есть идеи, почему проект не собирается? Не там копаю?

Repair IDE из меню File не помогает?

В своей версии Intellij Idea 2021.2.3 не смог найти Repair IDE ни в меню File ни в каком другом. Вроде бы должно быть File | Cache Recovery | Repair IDE, но странно что нету. @talex moved to Codidact

Возможно стоит обновится 2021 был три года назад.

Обновиться, к сожалению не могу. По другому проблема никак не решается? Это проблема кода Java, или проблема в IDE?

Это скорее всего проблема JDK, надо устанавливать правильную версию.

См. справку о версиях JDK и IntelliJ Idea: Java 23 поддерживается начиная с версии 2024.2, а ваша версия IntelliJ Idea 2021.2 поддерживает максимум Java 17.

Действительно, проблема в версии JDK и IDEA. Спасибо Nowhere Man. И всем, кто уделил внимание моему вопросу.
